# Redshift INNER JOIN does not filter out data and gives wrong COUNT result

Tags: amazon-redshift

Redshift cluster gives me wrong COUNT(*) result.

There are 2 tables. The first one has 24 256 599 rows and about 3 million user_hash_ids than the second table.

When I do anti join it shows me that about 19 million records does not have corresponding user_hash_id in the second table. Query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    usr_ykhvainitski.lnk_users_to_accounts l
LEFT JOIN usr_ykhvainitski.hub_users u
    ON l.user_hash_id = u.user_hash_id
WHERE u.user_hash_id IS NULL; -- 19 575 195
```

It gives me the right result.

But then I make COUNT with INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    usr_ykhvainitski.lnk_users_to_accounts l
    , usr_ykhvainitski.hub_users u
WHERE l.user_hash_id = u.user_hash_id;
```

That gives me 24 256 599. It hasn't filtered out records!!!

And execution plan shows me that it hasn't even scanned the second table:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    usr_ykhvainitski.lnk_users_to_accounts l
    , usr_ykhvainitski.hub_users u
WHERE l.user_hash_id = u.user_hash_id;

XN Aggregate  (cost=303207.50..303207.50 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  XN Seq Scan on lnk_users_to_accounts l  (cost=0.00..242566.00 rows=24256600 width=0)
```

But when I try to get some data from the second table or use EXISTS, IN, filtering, it gives correct results.

Regathering of statistics, changing distribution key did not help.

How can I make optimiser in Redshift to act in a way that I want and force it to scan the second table? I use ra3.xlplus cluster nodes.

Comment: Does this issue recreate with ANSI-92 standard SQL (FROM ... JOIN ... ON ...)?  Is it the query parser or the query optimizer?

Comment: Yes, the same with ANSI-92

Comment: So the optimizer.  Unfortunately Redshift uses several optimizers.  Have you been able to package this up into a transportable test case?

Comment: Haven't try to do that. Is there any guide how it can be done?

Comment: Not that I've seen or used.  Just need to create some sanitized versions of the table definitions (reduced size if at all possible) and the queries (which you have).  My guess is that a very simple version of the tables won't show the issue but rather there is some other factor in play.  So it likely comes down to paring down your existing tables until the problem disappears then backing up one step.  I'd start by copying your tables to new (test) tables and see if the problem continues with these.  Then seeing how small I can make these tables and have the issue continue.

Comment: Continue until you have things as small as possible and then sanitize the data content. If you can get it small enough it can be posted here or on sqlfiddle that makes getting help easy. Posting larger configs to some cloud storage can work too. There's a chance that any changes to the tables will make the issue go away - if this is the case and you have AWS support then you will want to get them involved as they can look into your cluster (with your permission) and see what is happening. If you think that this is a unique to your situation then you will want to take a snapshot to preserve it.